# Style-sheets in PyQt5 bakground-image pushbutton turns it into a no-image pushbutton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I use Qt-Designer to create a mainwindow and used stylesheets to make a button changeimage when pressed. however after running it the background-image and the pressed image does not work.

This is the stylesheet input from Qt-Designer:

```
QPushButton#House1 {
    border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);
}
QPushButton#House:pressed {
    border-image: url(:/img/Search_in_home.png);
}
```

This is my mainWindow.py :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import resources_rc
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(811, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        ###################house 1#######
        self.house2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(61, 21, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

        self.house1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house1.setStyleSheet("#House1 {\n"
"border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);\n"
"}\n"
"#House:Pressed {\n"
"    border-image: url(:/img/Search_in_home.png);\n"
"}")
        self.house1.setText("")
        self.house1.setObjectName("house1")
        ####################end #############
        self.house4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(61, 203, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house4.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house4.setText("")
        self.house4.setObjectName("house4")
        self.house2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(293, 21, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house2.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house2.setText("")
        self.house2.setObjectName("house2")
        self.house3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(524, 21, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house3.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house3.setText("")
        self.house3.setObjectName("house3")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(293, 384, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_8.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_8.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.pushButton_8.setText("")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.house5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(293, 203, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house5.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house5.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house5.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house5.setText("")
        self.house5.setObjectName("house5")
        self.house6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(524, 203, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house6.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.house6.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house6.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.house6.setText("")
        self.house6.setObjectName("house6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(61, 384, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_7.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_7.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.pushButton_7.setText("")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(524, 384, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_9.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_9.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);")
        self.pushButton_9.setText("")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 811, 27))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuAdmin = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAdmin.setObjectName("menuAdmin")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")
        self.actionSave = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave.setObjectName("actionSave")
        self.actionSave_As = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSave_As.setObjectName("actionSave_As")
        self.actionLogin = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionLogin.setObjectName("actionLogin")
        self.actionSign_Up = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSign_Up.setObjectName("actionSign_Up")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSave_As)
        self.menuAdmin.addAction(self.actionLogin)
        self.menuAdmin.addAction(self.actionSign_Up)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAdmin.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "SWTDI Main Window"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuAdmin.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Admin"))
        self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open"))
        self.actionSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.actionSave_As.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save As"))
        self.actionLogin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))
        self.actionSign_Up.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sign Up"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w   = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

resource file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>img/house.png</file>
    <file>img/house2.png</file>
    <file>img/NM_State_University_logo.png</file>
    <file>img/NMlogo_1colorstate_black.png</file>
    <file>img/NMlogo_1colorstate_red.tif</file>
    <file>img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png</file>
    <file>img/Gohomenew.png</file>
    <file>img/Search_in_home.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

The button was created by the line I commented out. but anyways 
I created another button with similar code I have seen around.

```
###################house 1#######
        self.house1 = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        #self.house1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.house1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(61, 21, 32, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.house1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

        self.house1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.house1.setStyleSheet("#House1 {\n"
"border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);\n"
"}\n"
"#House:Pressed {\n"
"    border-image: url(:/img/Search_in_home.png);\n"
"}")
        self.house1.setText("")
        self.house1.setObjectName("house1")
        ####################end #############
```

Comment: Please can you show the .qrc file

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45068963/edit) your question and add it.

Comment: ok I just added it

Comment: Which is `self.house1`, does it generate an error?

Comment: no, it runs fine, just no images on the pushbutton called house1

Comment: You have not completely copied the code, if you check, you have never created the self.house1 button. :P

Comment: I see, ok let me fix this.

Comment: Please correct it because I think I found the problem, but this depends on the corrected code that you show me.

Comment: I edited the question since code doesn't get formatted properly in the comment section . The images still do not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by not using the names correctly, QStyleSheet uses the objectName property, in your case the QPushButton self.house1:

```
self.house1.setObjectName("house1")
```

Before writing that line the button has no objectName (actually its objectName is "") so it is not appropriate to place the QStyleSheet by the objectName.

What you should do is place an objectName and then you can just assign the filtered QStyleSheet by its name.

```
self.house1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
self.house1.setObjectName("house1")
self.house1.setStyleSheet("#house1 {\n"
"border-image: url(:/img/Crystal_Clear_app_kfm_home.png);\n"
"}\n"
"#house1:Pressed {\n"
"    border-image: url(:/img/Search_in_home.png);\n"
"}")
```

This attribute is case-sensitive so you must place it exactly the same as `setObjectName()`.

For more information you should read the following:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html